# Where is my audit as Oracle sys audit is enable

Tags: oracle-11g, audit, sysdba

On an Oracle 11gr1 database, SYS audit is enabled:

```
SQL> show parameter audit

NAME                                 TYPE                             VALUE
------------------------------------ -------------------------------- ------------------------------
audit_file_dest                      string                           /oracle/admin/jde9dv/adump
audit_sys_operations                 boolean                          TRUE
audit_syslog_level                   string
audit_trail                          string                           DB_EXTENDED
```

But when I query the `SYS.AUD$` table there is nothing returned:

```
SQL> select count(*) from sys.aud$;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

When I go to `/oracle/admin/jde9dv/adump` folder, there is a lot of files but none contain my recent SYS activity ...

Where are my audit records ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to the party but anyways:

your AUDIT_TRAIL value should be set to DB,EXTENDED and not DB_EXTENDED.

You can change it with:

```
alter system set audit_trail=db,extended scope=spfile;
```

Bear in mind that after setting it to **DB,EXTENDED** you have to restart your instance for changes to take effect.

Find more on very handy Oracle's documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams016.htm#REFRN10006